# Probability to pick at least one pair of socks

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

There are 10 pairs of socks. What is the probability that in 4 socks chosen at random there is at least one pair.

My try: Let $A$ be an event of choosing exactly one pair of socks among 4 socks and $B$ be an event of choosing exactly two pairs,

$$P(A)=\frac{\binom{10}{1}\left(1-\frac{\binom{9}{1}}{\binom{18}{2}}\right)}{\binom{20}{4}}$$ and

$$P(B)=\frac{\binom{10}{2}}{\binom{20}{4}}$$

So the total probability is $P(A)+P(B)$.

But i know that some mistake is there in my solution... can any one help?

Comment: if we do without compliment method..whats wrong in my method

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Calculate $1$ minus the probability of the complementary event:**

The number of ways to choose $4$ out of $20$ socks is:

- Choose the $1$st sock out of $20$ socks
- Choose the $2$nd sock out of $19$ socks
- Choose the $3$rd sock out of $18$ socks
- Choose the $4$th sock out of $17$ socks

The number of ways to choose $4$ out of $20$ socks with no pairs is:

- Choose the $1$st sock out of $20$ socks
- Choose the $2$nd sock out of $18$ socks
- Choose the $3$rd sock out of $16$ socks
- Choose the $4$th sock out of $14$ socks

So the probability of choosing $4$ out of $20$ socks with at least one pair is:

$$1-\frac{20\cdot18\cdot16\cdot14}{20\cdot19\cdot18\cdot17}$$

---

Please note that I've essentially taken into account the order of the socks.

If I chose **not** to take it into account, then I would need to divide each result by $4!$.

But since this factor appears in both the numerator and the denominator, I can ignore it.

Comment: The OP did not ask for the correct calculation; he asked what is wrong with his own calculation.  This does not answer the question.

Comment: @WillO: It does, however, propose an alternative solution, which is nevertheless a constructive contribution (and at least $4$ people thought the same). Perhaps OP shouldn't mark it as the accepted answer, but it still does not deserve to be down-voted.

Comment: To make your answer clear: 

Let's say I'd like to know what is the probability that in $6$ six socks chosen randomly out of 10 pairs, there isn't any pair been chosen.

that will be: $$\frac{20 \cdot 18  \cdot  16 \cdot 14 \cdot 12 \cdot 10}{20 \cdot  19 \cdot  18 \cdot  17 \cdot  16 \cdot 15}$$

is that correct?

Answer (score 5):

There is *no* pair of socks among the 4 socks picked if and only if the 4 socks belong to different pairs. The number of possibilities for this to happen is $2^4\cdot\binom{10}{4}$ (first, choose which 4 pairs out of 10 are going to be hit; then for each pair, which of the two socks is picked).

In total, how many choices exist for choosing 4 socks out of 20? $\binom{20}{4}$. So the probability to "miss" every single pair of socks is $$\frac{2^4\cdot\binom{10}{4}}{\binom{20}{4}}=\frac{224}{323}$$, and the quantitity you are looking for is $1-\frac{2^4\cdot\binom{10}{4}}{\binom{20}{4}} = \frac{99}{323}.$

Comment: The OP did not ask for the correct calculation; he asked what is wrong with his own calculation. This does not answer the question.

Comment: @WillO: It does, however, propose an alternative solution, which is nevertheless a constructive contribution (and at least $2$ people thought the same). Perhaps OP shouldn't mark it as the accepted answer, but it still does not deserve to be down-voted.

Comment: how can you find the probability for  the case for which $4$ socks chosen randomly there is exactly two pairs?

Answer (score 1):

Your numerator in $P(A)$ is wrong—it isn't even an integer!  The numerator had to represent the number of ways that exactly one pair could be chosen:

$$^{10}\mathrm C_r\times\,^9\mathrm C_2\times2^2$$

Then you will get the same answer as CC: $\displaystyle\frac{99}{323}$

Answer (score 0):

This is late, but here is a general answer (studying for an exam, so I figured this was good practice).

There are 
$2n$ shoes ($n$ pairs).  So the denominator is ${2n\choose 2r}$ ie, choosing $2r$ shoes from $2n$ total.  We find our numerator  by calculating how many ways we have no matching pairs.  This means we would choose our shoes from the total pairs, and thus choose $2r$ from $n$, ${n\choose 2r}$.  We then would choose ${2\choose 1}$ shoes, and multiply this result $2r$ times.  This is because if we want to have no pairs, we would only select one shoe from every two to ensure there are no pairs chosen.  ${n\choose 2r}$ different shoe types and 
$\underbrace{{2\choose 1}\cdot{2\choose 1}\cdot\ldots \cdot{2\choose 1}}_{2r \text{ of these}}$ ways of choosing one shoe from each pair ensuring no correct pairs.  Distinguishing the chosen specified shoes leads to

$$\boxed{P(\text{no pairs})=\frac{{n\choose 2r}2^{2r}}{{2n\choose 2r}}}$$

If we want to find the probability of finding exactly one pair, then we note there are ${n\choose 1}$ ways to select one pair.  Then we want to select $2r-2$ pairs from $n-1$ shoes that remain, mathematically we can express this as ${n-1\choose 2r-2}$.  If we take one shoe from each pair, we would do this $2r-2$ times, so from the same reasoning as earlier, 
    $$\boxed{P(\text{one pair})=\frac{n{n-1\choose 2r-2}2^{2r-2}}{{2n\choose 2r}}}$$

Generalizing to getting exactly $i$ pairs

$$\boxed{P(\text{exactly i pairs})=\frac{{n\choose i}{n-i\choose 2r-2i}2^{2r-2i}}{{2n\choose 2r}}}$$